# Mapbox 3D satellite imagery feature

Tags: mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

Apple map's 3D imagery from C3 is a great feature. Does mapboxgl JS have something similar or have plans to implement something similar?

The reference link is a bit outdated, sorry.
https://9to5mac.com/2011/10/29/apple-acquired-mind-blowing-3d-mapping-company-c3-technologies-looking-to-take-ios-maps-to-the-next-level/

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that there are long-term plans to head in that direction, but they're a very long way from that now. They've just (October 2016) implemented 2.5D buildings (extrusions). It's a very, very long way from there to textured fully 3D terrains and cityscapes.

Cesium is probably a more promising avenue in the short-medium term.